# Which Windows Driver Kit is required to use with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, drivers, legacy-code

I've got some legacy code compiled with vs2008 which also includes driver code so I need to download a Driver Kit to build the driver portions, but I don't know what version of the Driver Kit I should download

Answer (score 2):

Prior to VS2012 the IDE wasn't integrated with WDK, and could only serve as invoker for the WDK build scripts. In order to know what DDK/WDK to use, you need to find out the **build target** of the driver, i.e., the OS where it will be installed (XP, Vista etc.). After that you should download the DDK/WDK that supports that OS. Note, newer kits have backwards compatibility to some extent (check the relevant documentation in MSDN).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use **WDK** build 6001.18000. To download see [vddk](http://visualddk.sysprogs.org/download/)